# Echoing volume letter and volume name without WMIC

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm working on a WinPE disk which requires that I list the letters and labels of a disk in command prompt to the user. Unfortunately, `WMIC logicaldisk ...`  gives me an error in my WinPE environment, so I have pieced together a few lines of batch which "replicate" what `WMIC` does. The code is as follows:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo :') do set colon=%%i
set drivetmp=%%a
set driveletter=%drivetmp%%colon%

echo Listing drives:
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo %driveletter% > tmpfile.t
    find "Volume Name" tmpfile.t >nul && set /p %vname% =< tmpfile.t
    find "Volume Name" tmpfile.t >nul && echo . Drive Letter: %driveletter% ..... %vname%
    del /q tmpfile.t
)
```

The code "works", however, for every line, it prints the same `%vname%` variable. For example, if my C: drive is named `Deployed Drive C` and I have drives `C, D, E, F, H and I`, the output will be like this:

```
C:\>test.cmd
Listing drives:
. Volume Label: c: ..... Volume Name : Deployed Drive C
. Volume Label: d: ..... Volume Name : Deployed Drive C
. Volume Label: e: ..... Volume Name : Deployed Drive C
. Volume Label: f: ..... Volume Name : Deployed Drive C
. Volume Label: h: ..... Volume Name : Deployed Drive C
. Volume Label: i: ..... Volume Name : Deployed Drive C
```

The drive letter changes as expected, the missing drives are excluded as expected, and if I type the commands manually, it also works! However, nomatter what I change the variables `%vname%` or `%a%` to, the script still performs the same. Is there something glaringly obvious that I am missing?

Comment: The output you report appears to be unrelated to the code you've posted. The likely solution to your problem would be that any use of `%var%` within a block statement (parenthesised series of statements) is replaced by the value of `var` at the time the entire block is parsed - before execution. To access the value as it changes through the operation of the loop, you'd need to invoke `delayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` (please see any number of SO articles related to `delayedexpansion` for more info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this does what you require:

```
@echo off
echo Listing drives:
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    if exist "%%a:\" (
       for /f "tokens=5,*" %%b in ('vol %%a: ^|find /i /v " serial number "') do echo Drive Letter: %%a:      Volume Name: %%c
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is much much cleaner than the code I posted. It works perfectly!